# Maps of the sphere!

Tags: general-topology, stereographic-projections, spheres

In the sphere we can introduce two patches that their union covers the whole sphere. Ok, I understand why we need at least two (because of the two poles). The maps in each chart is $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ and are defined such that they take the point with polar coordinates $\theta. \phi$ to the points $X,Y$ and $X',Y'$. They go on and say that these maps are the $$\phi_1: X+iY = e^{i\phi}\tan(\theta/2)$$ and $$\phi_2:X'+iY' = e^{i\phi}\cot(\theta/2),$$ and in the overlap we see that $$\phi_2 \circ \phi_1^{-1}(X,Y)=X'+iY'=1/(X+iY).$$
 I was wondering how to derive those but I do not see the way. Can you please help me understand why these maps are the way they are?

Comment: telling us the page number does not help if you don't say which book...

Comment: Oops, sorry, I ll fix it.

Comment: Do you know the geometry of stereographic projection? Also, there are multiple conventions (the center and radius of the sphere, the plane projected to), and naturally it matters exactly which one you're using. :)

Comment: Yes, I ve seen about it. It maps every point of the sphere on the plane except for the north pole that is mapped to $\infty$. But can you help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your formulas, $\phi$ denotes longitude and $\theta$ denotes angular distance from the south pole, so that $\theta' = \pi - \theta$ is the angular distance from the north pole.

Write complex numbers in polar form $z = \rho e^{i\phi}$, and consider the longitudinal cross section below. Your formulas come from trigonometry, noting that
$$
\rho = \tan(\theta/2) = \cot(\theta'/2).
$$

In a bit more detail, one coordinate chart is induced by sterographic projection from the north pole. The other chart is *the complex conjugate of* stereographic projection from the south pole.

The conjugate is omitted in your formulas, but is needed because
$$
\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{\rho} e^{-i\phi}.
$$
(This oversight is not uncommon even in the mathematics literature.)

[image: Longitudinal section of stereographic projection]